# Why is a Rails API application configured to store session data in cookies by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, session, cookies, rails-api

When I create a rails api using `rails new my_api --api`, it produces a rails application which by default is configured to store session data in cookies (it can be seen in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`) even though a rest api is not supposed to necessarily talk to browser clients.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Previously, the default `SessionStore` was `ActiveRecord::SessionStore`. In Rails 4.0.0 it was changed to `CookieStore` and `ActiveRecord::SessionStore` was factored out into a separate gem:

https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store

The change was documented in the Rails 4.0.0 changelog:

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore is extracted out of Rails into a gem 
activerecord-session_store. 

Setting config.session_store to :active_record_store will no 
longer work and will break if the activerecord-session_store gem 
isn't available.
```

Noted in this commit:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0ffe19056c8e8b2f9ae9d487b896cad2ce9387ad

Various blogs have commented on the change as one geared toward performance, and Rails 4's included many other features that were factored out into separate gems. This does not mean you should not use them, it just wasn't deemed to be needed in the core framework.